# problem in finding a function of a toolbox in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Why I can not see any result for the function of a toolbox(like topoplot in EEGlab) when I type its name in the help window in Matlab([search result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iFI6.png)) but when I type it with help or doc command in command line I get the result([help result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fztpL.jpg))? Why these search results are not same?

Comment: `topoplot` is not a nativ function from MATLAB. If it has no description as comments in the line abov or below the keyword `function` at definition, you won't see anything if you type `help`. What irritates me is that you claim to see a non-native toolbox in the docs of MATLAB...

Comment: @max Could you please see the pictures that I added to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as `topoplot` is not a MATLAB-native function, it is also not part of the official documentation. Which is why you won't see something in the docs (and MATLAB asks you if you have ment something else).

The information that you get when you call `help topoplot` is what is written as comments at the very beginning of the file or just after the keyword `function` in the definition.

```
% this is what you get
% this line too

% this not
function test()
end
```

if you now call `help test`

[image: command window]

This also works after the keyword

```
function test()
% this is what you get
% this is the second line

% you won't see this
end
```

[image: command window output]